# How can one build multiple UI layers with flex and flash?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

How can one build multiple UI layers with flex and flash? Note, i use amfphp framework for my back end.

Answer (score 0):

The backend shouldn't matter.

It really depends what you mean by multiple layers.  Many people use a [ViewStack](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/ViewStack.html) to layer views on top of each other.  The nature of a ViewStack is that only one view is shown at once.

A [TabNavigator](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/containers/TabNavigator.html) is a similar control; but comes with built in navigation.